# Exception raised while accessing keyvault in Azure through C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I had below code to fetch key vault secrets in Azure:

```
   var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetToken));
    var sec = await kv.GetSecretAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeURI"]);
    secretValue = sec.Value ;
```

In App Config I had:

```
<add key="SomeURI" value="https://baseURL/KeyName/b75cabsdf45667nhjhe516c674457" />
```

Since I have been using this many times in my application, I have created a class and called that class. The class looks like this:

```
public static class KeyVaultFetch
    {
        public async static Task<string> GetCachedSecret(string secretname)
        {           
            try
            {
                string BaseUri =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyvaultBaseURI"].ToString();

                var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetToken));
                var secretbundle = await kv.GetSecretAsync($"{BaseUri}{secretname}").ConfigureAwait(false);
                return secretbundle.Value;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Exception raised in GetCachedSecret.");
                log.Error("Exception Details: " + ex.Message);
                log.Error("Inner Exception Details: " + ex.InnerException);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public static async Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
        {
            try
            {
                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
                ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
                AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);
                if (result == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
                return result.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Exception raised while Getting token : " + ex.Message);
                log.Error("Inner Exception Details: " + ex.InnerException);
                throw;
            }
        }
        
    }
```

And I have written below line to get the secret every time:

```
secretValue = await KeyVaultFetch.GetCachedSecret(keyName);
```

But I'm geeting the below exception , when I run my code :

```
Exception raised in GetCachedSecret.
Exception Details: Invalid ObjectIdentifier: https://baseURL/. Bad number of segments: 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use GetSecretAsync with 2 parameters:

```
await kv.GetSecretAsync(BaseUri, secretname);
```

At least that's how it is in our apps :)

Comment: does the base URI also has "/secrets" appended in the last?

Comment: Nope, just the key vault URL

Comment: both signatures should work though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclientextensions.getsecretasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault_KeyVaultClientExtensions_GetSecretAsync_Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault_IKeyVaultClient_System_String_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_ -- what does that error actually mean??